# What does a single line path reference indicate in shell bash scripting

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to decipher and fix a application within a docker container that uses shell scripting and python scripts. In this block of code, what does the single line that contains a path mean?

```
start=$(date +%s.%N)
# generate deep segmentation
# preprocessing for liver
/extra/preprocessing
dur=$(echo "$(date +%s.%N) - $start" | bc)
printf "*******preprocessing time: %.6f seconds
" $dur
```

I understand that the `start` and `dur` variables are just reporting processing time, but what does the `/extra/preprocessing` line do? Is it just navigating?

it then moves on to blocks of code that look like this

```
start=$(date +%s.%N)
# generate deep segmentation
/pythondir/miniconda/bin/python /extra/python/segment_test.py --model_name=model_wholebody --network=206 --batchSize_lmk=4 --viewName=viewall --loss_fun= --lmk_num=18 
dur=$(echo "$(date +%s.%N) - $start" | bc)
printf "*******segmentation time: %.6f seconds
" $dur
```

again there is a `dur` setup to report processing time, but I am finding the line `/pythondir/miniconda/bin/python /extra/python/segment_test.py --model_name=model_wholebody --network=206 --batchSize_lmk=4 --viewName=viewall --loss_fun= --lmk_num=18` a little bit confusing. I understand that the second path in this line is accessing a python script and all the flags are arguments given to that script, but what does the first path indicate? `/pythondir/miniconda/bin/python`

Comment: It is running the script `/extra/preprocessing` and also later running `/pythondir/miniconda/bin/python /extra/python/segment_test.py` with arguments   `--model_name=model_wholebody ......`. What is the first line of `/extra/preprocessing`?

Comment: I get the following error ```/OUTPUTS/bash2_test.sh: line 12:    20 Killed                  /extra/preprocessing``` and then a buch of Traceback errors after that.

Comment: `/pythondir/miniconda/bin/python` is simply the absolute path to the python processor the script wants to use. There may be multiple python's on the path, but script specifically wants a miniconda python. It will use miniconda packages for instance instead of system packages.

Comment: read the trackback as well as the first line to understand what language it is.

Comment: @wander95 but ```/extra/preprocessing``` isn't referencing a script, correct? isn't it just a path to a directory? I feel like the space between ```/pythondir/miniconda/bin/python``` and ``` /extra/python/segment_test.py``` is throwing me off, and again it seems like ```/pythondir/miniconda/bin/python``` is just a path to a directory and not a script

Comment: here is the traceback error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/extra/python/segment_test.py", line 67, in <module>
    test_subs = generate_sublist.dir2list(test_img_root_dir,test_img_list_file)
  File "/extra/python/generate_sublist.py", line 26, in dir2list
    subs = os.listdir(img_root_dir)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/OUTPUTS/Data_2D/img'```

Comment: Why do you think `/extra/preprocessing` is the path to a directory? It's a path, to be sure, but paths can reference *anything* in the file system: files, directories, sockets, named pipes, character devices, block devices, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> but what does the /extra/preprocessing line do?

It just launches executable named `preprocessing` located in `/extra` path. If it's not there you shall see error message but the script will continue regardless.

Same for 2nd executable `/pythondir/miniconda/bin/python`. By using absolute path you ensure exactly binary you want is used, while using `python` may call different one, depending on current environment (like PATH, or shell aliases etc).

Comment: It is all inside a docker container, so I think the absolute paths are the correct ones